# Pick two values to form new key-and-value pairs

Tags: underscore.js

With an array of objects, how to do this with underscore?

---

```
var abc = [{a:'a1',b:'b1',c:'c1'},  {a:'a2',b:'b2',c:'c2'}];

var ab = SOME_FUNC(abc, [a,b]);

// so that ab is {'a1':'b1', 'a2':'b2'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I change a bit Gruff Bunny's answer

```
var SOME_FUNC = function(list, props) {
      var obj = {};
      _.each( list, function (value) {
        obj[  value[props[0]] ] = value[props[1]];
      });
      return obj;
}
```